# I'm currently stuck trying to migrate my database to a previous migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having difficulty; I can't rollback my database to a previous migration and I get no error messages. I'm kind of stuck - some help would be appreciated.

What I have tried:

When I run the command

```
dotnet ef database update "previous migration"
```

on my locally set up database, the command works and does as intended and applies the update to my database.

When I try to run this on another database with same migrations except for one, I can't rollback to the migration I need which is the previous one to apply the update to my database.

I get a response saying :

> No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.

Comment: Check the migrations history table. Is it in expected state?

Comment: the history table remains unchanged and ii dont underestand why. in other words the  migration that should be removed doesnt get removed.